# How to prevent deletion of my Google Scholar profile flagged as a duplicate of a colleague's?

Tags: funding, google-scholar

My Google Scholar account is scheduled to be made private on 25th July as it is flagged as a duplicate of a close colleague's. We have worked at the same department, we share the first and middle name, and we share a number of papers, but we have separate spatial locations, passports, brains, hands, etc. I promise. Like many scientists, Google has us confused.

Edit to add: Google seemed to sort itself out and maintain both our profiles. It seemed like a bug in the display, but the system had managed to separate our identities.

Comment: Is having a Google scholar profile and touting your own h-index the norm in your field?  In pure math, the former is common but not expected, but the latter would not be well received, I think.

Comment: Yes it's pretty normal in our field (unfortunately or otherwise). I am advised to mention it on proposals. But of course, it will look a bit silly if the webpage is gone after a proposal is submitted. I am curious though, how difficult is it to get funding in pure maths?

Comment: Not seeing a change in "an hour" would seem normal. A human might need to be involved in a fix.

Comment: @Helen Large grants are quite competitive, but we don't rely much on citation metrics to determine the merit of someone's work.

Comment: @Helen *Suggestion separate from answering the question:* You might consider to establish a profile on [ORCID](https://orcid.org/) or a similar  where *you* may identify your work, and curate your list e.g., via the publication's doi without delay until a body like Google *correctly* identifies yours. There is nothing wrong to use multiple ones, too (example [John Kitchin](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/publications.html)). Databases like Scopus / Web of Science may facilitate this task, some services cross-link each other, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if they will reply to you, but you should try contacting Google scholar.  Here is their email: scholar-support@google.com  (found on [this page](https://scholar.google.com/intl/ja/scholar/help.html#corrections), under the court opinion question).

Some other ideas are:

- make an academic webpage with all the relevant info, so people can check that
- try recreating your profile after it gets deleted
- in addition to mentioning your Google scholar profile on your application, you could mention another one (e.g., Web of Science, Semantic Scholar, Microsoft Academic) which will hopefully not disappear

That said, I don't know how it would be viewed in your field, but if your profile gets deleted/merged with another person's, and someone looks for you on Google scholar,  *hopefully* they will at least be able to find your papers, which should be sufficient evidence if they're just trying to verify citation metrics you state.