Paper appears on my Google Scholar account but not when searched
I published a paper in an open access computer science conference last year (ECAI 2023, if it matters). The paper is on the conference website, arXiv, researchgate, and some additional websites it apparently added automatically to.
The paper appears in my Google Scholar account, and also when searched inside quotes, but not with a regular scholar search even with the paper's exact name (the name is unique and there is no paper with a similar name). The paper can be found easily when searched on google (not scholar).
Why is it so? I'm afraid it may inhibit other scientists from finding it. I did got two citations, so I don't think it's something with the rating of the paper. Can I fix it somehow? It's already been like this for about a year.

We have no insight into just how Google Scholar works (or doesn't work).

Did you try contacting google scholar?  At some point I found an email address for them - see https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/171200/19607
